# How can I give an internal extrude with proportional offset that does not change the global z axis?

Tags: mesh, extrude

Initial mesh

[image]

Objective partially achieved through Extrude Faces Along Normals or pressing E > Esc > Alt + S

[image]

How to avoid displacement in the Z axis so that everything is aligned?

[image]

Note: I need a proportional offset

[image]

Comment: Add Shift-Z after your Extrude along Normals hotkey. I.e: E > Esc > Alt + S >Shift + Z. That will exclude extrusion on the Z axis but allow it in the X and Y directions.

Comment: Hello friend, thank you very much for the answer. In this sequence of shortcuts Shift + Z has no effect.

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file in that case. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/315392/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: The file is now available

Comment: Ok. The Extrude along Normals won't work in this case because the normals on the sloping faces aren't horizontal so those faces are naturally extruded up at an angle and I guess the scaling is giving different results because the size of each ring of faces is different on the sloping section of the object. Does E > S > Shift-Z (without Enter) and then dragging the mouse give you the result you want? It's a bit difficult to tell but the ring sizes look pretty consistent to me.

Comment: The problem in this case is that the offset is irregular. I would like to keep the offset at the same value for all faces. Just for context, I'm trying to reproduce this model in low poly
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/mp9-counter-strike-2-3dbcae165cb64385b83bf620b1803c80 (perhaps this model can help in finding a solution to this problem)

Comment: As @moonboots says I doubt it's possible. In any case, who is going to notice small inconsistencies like that?

Comment: True. Shift-Z after extrude gives a satisfactory result. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.................

Comment: A few seconds too late! :^)

Comment: eh eh ;) ..............................

Comment: Hello friend, thank you very much for the answer. The Shift + Z shortcut blocked changes to the Z axis, but the offsets were different sizes.
For me, the idea would be for the Shift + Z shortcut to work in conjunction with Extrude Faces Along Normal, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: OK you want the same offset for all the extrusions, not sure how to do it...

Comment: That's right. I made the .blend file available to better understand the problem.